# 'Past Participle Verb Form' vs 'Past Participle Adjective'?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

> 1. *This room [is **cleaned**] every day.*
> 2. *The window [is **broken**].*

In the first sentence, we have a **'Past Participle (Verb)'**.
In the second sentence, we have a **'Past Participle Adjective'**.

More examples:

> 3. *He has **broken** his glass.* <-- 'Broken' as a **'Past Participle' (Verb)**
> 4. *A **broken** glass.* <-- 'Broken' as an **'Adjective'**

I've got two questions:

- Are there rules for distinguishing 'P.P. adjectives' from 'P.P. verbs' for all sentences?
- Can all 'P.P. verbs' be used as 'P.P. adjectives'? (For example: The word *'cleaned'* as an adjective)

Comment: Are you sure that your second example ("The window is broken") isn't ambiguous?

Comment: Are you sure that the "broken" in your fourth example ("a broken glass") cannot be a past-participle ***verb*** form?

Comment: @F.E. Do you mean maybe the window is broken every day, or perhaps on special occasions?

Comment: @Araucaria And there's also the instructional register: do this, do that, this happens, that happens. Also, there's present-tense prose. Though, usually it seems that the classical examples in textbooks use past-tense versions, e.g *"The vase was broken"*.

Comment: @F.E. Aaargh, it seems that my being awake times of the day and your comments are getting out of sinc! I didn't entirely understand that but will have allook tomorrow before I start teaching :) [Would be really nice to see a nice good post on here somewhere - nudge ]

Comment: @Araucaria I'm way too swamped! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Adjectival passives vs verbal passives: it be an interesting topic, but there's already been quite a bit written on it, and if one tries to write a post on it, it's like, where does one start and what does one leave out. Besides, it's another useful shibboleth. :)

Comment: @F.E. Thanks a million. Adjectival passives vs Verbal passives. This is the exact thing I want to learn. You asked me about the second & the fourth examples. Well, I think 'A broken glass' is definitely an adjective (Adjectival passive = Past Participle Adjective), just like 'The catch is broken'. But when we say 'He has broken his glass', this is definitely a verb (verbal passive).

Comment: @F.E. But my problem is: When I want to translate this kind of sentences to my mother tongue, I can't understand words such as 'Broken', 'Chosen' and other past participles. Because sometimes they're verbs and sometimes they're adjectives. It confuses me. And I can't understand them easily. So I asked my question here, because I want to identify them.

Comment: If you're doing translation, then it's possible that you're trying to translate the intention (the meaning) of the sentence. To do that, the surrounding context is important. That will tell you whether the situation being described by the sentence is a dynamic one or a stative one; and so, that's probably how you'd want to translate it into the destination language. -- Adjectival passives are actually adjectives, and they are generally used to describe stative situations. Verbal passives are passive clauses/VPs and are commonly used to describe both dynamic situations and stative situations.

Comment: This is an example of why naming parts of speech is such a useless activity; often the information isn't available. Schrödinger's participle -- you can't tell which one it is until you add material and force a grammaticality reading. But that's not the original sentence -- in the original sentence **you just can't tell**. Luckily, it doesn't matter, because the distinction is irrelevant to the grammar and to the meaning -- it's just academic pilpul.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there rules for distinguishing 'P.P. adjectives' from 'P.P. verbs' for all sentences?

No. In fact, your second example ("The window is broken") is ambiguous. The "stative passive" reading with a participial adjective is certainly more common, but an "eventive passive" (regular passive) reading with a past participle is also possible, given appropriate context: "The security camera footage shows part of the event. […] At 1:13 AM, the window is broken by a projectile arriving from off-camera — apparently a thrown rock."

> Can all 'P.P. verbs' be used as 'P.P. adjectives'? (For example: The word 'cleaned' as an adjective)

If the verb is transitive, then, probably; it's a common enough pattern that if you have a good reason (in a given context) to use a given participle as an adjective, then your audience will probably be able to follow you.

That said, some past participles would be a stretch; even though "stand" can sometimes be transitive ("the teacher stood one student at each corner of the room"), it's hard to imagine a situation where you would describe someone as "stood" rather than "standing", simply because the latter is such a common word that you'd need a reason to avoid it.

If the verb is *not* transitive, then this is likely to be too much of a stretch; you can draft an intransitive verb into service as a transitive one if needed, and you can draft the past participle of a transitive verb into service as an adjective if needed, but doing both at once would probably just confuse your audience.

Answer (score 0):

Thought-provoking question!

I think we need to look at the *sentence structure* or else it'll be difficult to find it out. While *transitive verbs* make our task easy as they'd have a **direct object** following them. the problem occurs when the verb is *intransitive*.

But then, if you use 'intransitive' verbs, the sentence won't look complete without explaining the verb. For instance, 'break' is transitive and intransitive both (just like 'clean'); now you'll have to **talk about the verb** further in order to make the sentence complete.

> He has broken - *won't work*

The moment you add '....his glass', we can make out that it is used as a verb.

The adjective pattern will be different than the 'verb pattern' in those sentences with PP.

In English, a 'single word' on its own may stand ambiguous. That's why we say, **context** is important.

[But let natives come with their take on this].

Comment: This is an example of why naming parts of speech is such a useless activity; often the information isn't available. Schrödinger's participle -- you can't tell which one it is until you add material and force a grammaticality reading. But that's not the original sentence -- in the original sentence **you just can't tell**. Luckily, it doesn't matter, because the distinction is irrelevant to the grammar and to the meaning -- it's just academic pilpul.